# Escaping with this PHP function is unsafe?

Tags: php, escaping, sql-injection

If I escape data with

```
addcslashes($input,chr(0x00) . chr(0x0d) . chr(0x0a) . chr(0x1a) . chr(0x5c) . chr(0x27) . chr(0x22));
```

would that be enough to stop SQLi? I have all required characters there, so, as long as the $input is UTF-8, there should be no problems with that itself. Of course invalid use of the method or something similar can cause SQLi. I'm using this because I'd like to escape without connecting to the database and I know my input is UTF-8, if it's not, I convert it.

Comment: Why would you like to escape without connection to the database? You will eventually connect to it, right?

Comment: It seems the purpose of this made confusion. I am caching SQL results on a very static like page, so, 95% of times the connection to the database is entirely useless. I could just escape the query, compare it to the cache and fetch the appropriate cache data. If I escape with the native functions, it would establish the connection. Connecting to the database takes over 90% of my page load time. That's why the avoidance.

Comment: I see. My impression is that you should move the data escaping to a different layer in your application. I'm not sure how possible this is for you, but it would be ideal to escape data just before querying the database.

Comment: I'm doing just that. Escaping before doing the actual query. However, if my db driver sees a cache file, then it will load the data from the cache rather than connection and querying. If the cache is not valid, or does not exist, then it connects to the database and queries. The problem is that I can't compare cache files (The query) without escaping, so, I need an offline escaping method.

Comment: Maybe you should revise your cache invalidation strategy. Just my opinion.

Comment: Escaping is needed in order to cache SQL queries. I can't just take the prepared, but non-binded version of the query and use it as the identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using this because I'd like to escape without connecting to the database

For the specific case of MySQL that is simply not possible. Until the connection is made, PHP does not know what character encoding is being used to communicate with the database, and hence it doesn't know which `'` bytes in your string correspond to `'` characters. If your connection is always UTF-8, you'd be safe, but if that code was deployed on a server that defaults to, say, Shift-JIS, you might escape a partial-character `'` byte incorrectly and actually *cause* an SQL injection where there was none previously.

For other databases, that's the wrong sort of escaping entirely; ANSI SQL and most DBMSs use a doubled `''` to denote an apostrophe in a string literal, and don't escape any other characters. MySQL can also support this through the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES config option; again, PHP cannot know whether that option is in use before it makes a connection.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've been thinking. I enforce the connection to UTF-8, and I enforce the input to always be UTF-8, and my escaping method works with UTF-8, so, I guess I'm safe. And this is for MySQL, sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use the inbuilt [filter](http://uk.php.net/filter) method, and, like said above, functions dedicated to preventing injection. You can also use prepared statements in addition to all this. Don't try to rely on your own attempts at sanitising like this - there are tried and tested common functions used on a day to day basis that work, and if you find a bug or flaw with them, be sure to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MySQL function library, the [documentation](http://us.php.n.et/mysql_real_escape_string) strongly suggest that you use their method to sanitize DB input.

> [mysql_real_escape_string] must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.

Edit: I am aware that you don't want to connect to the DB first to do this; however, this is considered to be the *best practice* by PHP.  @Bobince's answer explains the details of why this is the case

Comment: He also said that he also wants to not have to connect to a database.

Comment: I am aware of that.  I'm pointing out the best-practice here. @bobince went into the details that I neglected about why he should do as the documentation says.